# Tensorflow - getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, anaconda, glibc

I have installed tensorflow 0.10 in Anaconda2 -> Python 2.7.

OS: RHEL6.8

I was getting below error when I try to run

```
python -c "import tensorflow"

ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)

I have glibc_2.12 in the host. I installed glibc_2.14 in another dir.

Now I am running the command as below:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib

python -c "import tensorflow"
```

Now I am getting a different error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Is this still reproducible in tensorflow 1.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Answer (score 0):

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why you should never do that, and what to do instead.